# Regex capture 1 character

Tags: r, regex

Whenever english character of length 1 exists, I want that to be combined with the previous text.

```
gsub('(.*)\\s+([a-zA-Z]{1})', "\\1\\2", 'Anti-Candida a ингибинов')

Anti-Candidaa ингибинов
```

For the example below, it should return `'Anti-Candida am ингибинов'` as **'am'** is of length 2.

```
gsub('(.*)\\s+([a-zA-Z]{1})', "\\1\\2", 'Anti-Candida am ингибинов')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
\W+([a-zA-Z])\b
```

replace with `\\1`. The trick here is to match a word boundary after the single letter.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oIqGBZ/2)

Your regex will work as well, if you just add that `\b` at the end.